# Convert time into Timer Interval using C#

Tags: c#, web-applications, timer

I am comparing timing and based on that assigning interval to timer.

I have 2 datetime,

For i.e.

```
Datetime dt1 = 04:00:00;
Datetime dt2 = 15:20:28;
Datetime dt3 = 24:00:00;
```

Now, I want to set interval to call timer at 04:00:00. Think that, right now, time is 15:20:28, so to call timer at 04:00:00, I will need to do some operation.

So, what should i do to call `Timer` at 04:00:00 ???
In short, I want to check out time, if it is not 04:00 AM then set proper interval to call timer at 04:00 AM.

And convert time into timer interval ???

Comment: What does `dt1 + dt2` even mean? It makes no sense to add two date/time values together.

Comment: i want to set interval to call timer so doing sum of 2 time, dnt knw it is possible or not...

Comment: I suspect you want the TimeSpan class, other than that your question makes no sense.

Comment: @JeetenParmar: Think about what a `DateTime` value means. It's a *date* and a time. What happens if you add June 15th 2013 11:20am and (say) June 19th 1976 8:48am. What result would you expect?

Comment: @JeetenParmar: Your edited question still tries to add two DateTimes. It's still meaningless (let alone impossible).

Comment: And it's not clear what you mean by "set interval to call timer" - do you mean you have a `Timer`, and you want it to tick next time it's 4am, so you need to work out the length of time until then? What is `dt3` meant to be?

Comment: again check out my edited post.

Comment: Convert your dates into TimeSpans and subtract one from the other (dt1 - Now for example) to get the difference.
This difference should be the interval you need.

Comment: what do you mean by call timer..?? do you want to set interval of a timer object..?

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse, yes... I want to set proper interval to call timer at 4:00 AM

Comment: can you show us some more code so that wat you are trying to do..?? what do u mean set the timer at 4:00 AM do you mean that you want your timer interval to elapse everyday at 4 am..??

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse, Yes, rite... I want timer interval to elapse everydat at 4 AM

Comment: this is a winforms application..?

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse, nope... It is web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call Timer. Timer wake up when it's interval ended.
What you can do is to calculate the TimeSpan from now to 4AM, and set Timer interval to this value.
Or more efficient, architecture approach, is to set the timer interval to every n seconds, and when Timer wake up to check if it's 4.

Here is a sample code for the first option:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(new DateTime(2013,06,15,04,00,00).Ticks- DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        long ticks = ts.Ticks;
        long divide=    (long)Math.Pow(10, 7);
        long span = ticks / divide;
        timer.Interval = (int)span*1000;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: I am thinking to set timer interval properly when time is not 4 AM. Once interval ends and ElapsedEventHandler is called, set timer to 24 hours. What about it ???

Comment: It is not perfect answer but I got some help from your answer. so marking it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = ... // next 4:00 AM from now
var timer = new Timer(callback, null, dt - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

check if this will do for you